# HIVE - Update a Column value from Record A using the same table Record B

Tags: hive

I'm looking for a sample Hive Update query that uses the same table as source to update the column. Eg: having 2 records with id as common and one record has the acc no. and i am trying to update the same acc no. in the another record. Can u pl. share if you have ?
tried the below but not helping..

```
UPDATE a FROM  udc.hive.horton.eoquality.testtable  a,
(
select id, cust_id from (select cust_id,id,row_number() over (partition by id by evnt_dt_pst_ts desc) as findacc
from
udc.hive.horton.eoquality.testtable) where findacc = 1 and cust_id <> '' and id = '1087'
) b
SET cust_id= b. cust_id
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I think update is not available in Hive.

Comment: _"but not helping.."_ isn't helping to understand the problem. Also, check UPDATE syntax in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update